# How to get the most recent element by id in MySQL table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

[image]I tried the below code to get the last inserted id so as to insert it to another table but somehow using `$this->$conn->lastInsertId()` doesn't seem to work.

Anyone has any idea?

```
if (!( $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO company(company_name,address_line1,address_line2,postal_code,country,contact_no,email,wifi_name,website_url,contact_person,parent_id,created_by,created_date,updated_date,deleted, wifi_name2) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"))) {
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $this->conn->errno . ")" . $this->conn->error;
    } else {
        if (!$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssiissis', $name, $address_line1, $address_line2, $postal_code, $country, $phone, $email, $wifi, $url, $contact, $p_id, $staff_id, $today, $updated, $deleted, $wifi2)) {
            echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
        } else {
            if (!$stmt->execute()) {
                echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
                return FALSE;
            } else {
                echo $this->$conn->lastInsertId();
                $stmt->close();
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @user2342558 Already resolved.  There was an error in using $this->$conn->lastInsertId(), should use $stmt->insert_id.  Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be correct.

Maybe you don't have the field `ID AUTOIMCREMENT PRIMARY` on that table.

`lastInsertId()` can return the new ID only if the field is `AUTOIMCREMENT PRIMARY`.

Try also do query this to see if you get the last inserted id:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$lastInsertId = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

If the aboves aren't your case, you must analyze every single step to discover the issue:

- run the script to see what it prints
- see in the database if the new row was inserted and what it contains, particularly the `id` field
- try yo make the insert directly in phpmyadmin and then execute `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()' to see if the manually query works

Comment: Yes, is using autoincrement.  There are different variant of accessing the db and so it is a bit confusing.

Comment: getting a 0 when I execute this: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()

Comment: are you sure that the table has an ID autoincrement PRIMARY KEY? post the table structure

Comment: PK and AI are ticked for the id of this table.

Comment: post the table structure in your question.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, which I believe I am not using the pdo accessing method, this works:

```
$stmt->insert_id;
```